# how can I solve Apache nifi openssl error?

Tags: openssl, apache-nifi

After upgraded the apache nifi from 1.13 to 1.18, I've started to seen that error as below. Also I can see same error on webgui from some flow whic is use that certificate.

WARN [main] d.o.a.n.s.u.c.NiFiLegacyCipherProvider Insecure Cipher Provider Algorithm [PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL] cipher requested
org.apache.nifi.deprecation.log.DeprecationException: Reference Class [org.apache.nifi.security.util.crypto.NiFiLegacyCipherProvider] ClassLoader [org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.18.0.nar-unpacked]]
at org.apache.nifi.deprecation.log.StandardDeprecationLogger.getExtendedArguments(StandardDeprecationLogger.java:63)
at org.apache.nifi.deprecation.log.StandardDeprecationLogger.warn(StandardDeprecationLogger.java:54)
at org.apache.nifi.security.util.crypto.NiFiLegacyCipherProvider.getCipher(NiFiLegacyCipherProvider.java:66)
at org.apache.nifi.encrypt.PasswordBasedCipherPropertyEncryptor.getCipher(PasswordBasedCipherPropertyEncryptor.java:119)
at org.apache.nifi.encrypt.PasswordBasedCipherPropertyEncryptor.getEncryptionCipher(PasswordBasedCipherPropertyEncryptor.java:84)
at org.apache.nifi.encrypt.CipherPropertyEncryptor.encrypt(CipherPropertyEncryptor.java:52)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.serialization.StandardFlowSerializer.addConfiguration(StandardFlowSerializer.java:562)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.serialization.StandardFlowSerializer.addControllerService(StandardFlowSerializer.java:657)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.serialization.StandardFlowSerializer.addProcessGroup(StandardFlowSerializer.java:315)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.serialization.StandardFlowSerializer.transform(StandardFlowSerializer.java:111)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.serialization.StandardFlowSerializer.transform(StandardFlowSerializer.java:79)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController.serialize(FlowController.java:1423)
at org.apache.nifi.persistence.StandardFlowConfigurationDAO.serializeControllerStateToTempFile(StandardFlowConfigurationDAO.java:235)
at org.apache.nifi.persistence.StandardFlowConfigurationDAO.saveFlow(StandardFlowConfigurationDAO.java:210)
at org.apache.nifi.persistence.StandardFlowConfigurationDAO.saveXml(StandardFlowConfigurationDAO.java:203)
at org.apache.nifi.persistence.StandardFlowConfigurationDAO.save(StandardFlowConfigurationDAO.java:191)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService.load(StandardFlowService.java:560)
at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:67)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:1073)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:572)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.contextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:1002)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a deprecation warning. The 'PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL' and similar password based algorithms are planned to be deprecated in a future NiFi release due to not meeting the NiFi project's security threshold. A more secure Password Based Encryption alternative would be BCrypt, SCrypt, Argon2, PBKDF2. Your NiFi configuration (nifi.properties) would need to be migrated to an updated algorithm. The relevant properties in nifi.properties are `nifi.sensitive.props.key=????` and
`nifi.sensitive.props.algorithm=PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL` which provide the encryption for flow.xml.gz. An updated sensitive properties algorithm would be `nifi.sensitive.props.algorithm=NIFI_PBKDF2_AES_GCM_256`.

I believe you can update your configuration using this command: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#updating-the-sensitive-properties-algorithm

Here's some additional reading: https://exceptionfactory.com/posts/2021/07/29/deciphering-apache-nifi-component-property-encryption/